# In Django, how do I return a form back to a Javascript function?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my template, I have javascript that send a GET call to a Django method. In this method I would like to return a blank form back to the template. Here's my javascript:

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(xhr, ready){
        var url = window.location.pathname + "dev/" + report_id + "/" + report_url + "/";
        xhr(url, {
            method: "get"
        }).then(
            function(response){
                var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
                //do stuff
            }
        );
    });
```

Here's what's happening in my Django view:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MyForm()
        data = json.dumps({
            'form': form,
        })

        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        #do other stuff
```

Here's the error I'm getting right now:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <development.dev_forms.MyForm object at 0x7f3a8dd07e50> is not JSON serializable
```

So it seems I can't serialize a Django Form. So, I'd like to return the fields of this form to the template somehow. What other ways can I do this? Is there a way to get the HTML of all the fields? Then I could build a dictionary myself. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to render the form and then pass it back to the ajax call:

```
ctx = {'form': MyForm()}

data = {
    "form": render_to_string("app/form_template.html", ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        }
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Then in get the form using `json_response.form` in `success` function of your ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to return an html form. If you want to display a form with ajax, you should do that. For example, you could use `render_to_response` with a template that renders the form you want, passing the form in the context of the template.....

I don't know what do you want to do with the form, but i think something like this could help you:

**view file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MyForm()
        return render_to_response('app/template.html', {"form": form})
    else:
        #do other stuff
```

**app/template.html**

```
<form action='some_url' method='get'>
    {{form}}
    <input type='submit' value'Save' />
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything to my Javascript. What I have is a page with a bunch of links. Depending on which link I click, a different form needs to be rendered. I am trying to use JS to retrieve that form.

Comment: I don't know that way of using ajax, but its probably you have to modify it a bit to get it work. I know my method works with this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I'm sorry @Di-Zou. I made a mistake and write POST as the form method but it should be GET. Look if it works now. Just change the method of the form